# ssis OLEDB Source connection manager

Tags: ssis, ssis-2008

My source Database is getting restored every 15 mins. When I tried to load the data from source DB, it is kicking me out, hence my package is failing. Is there anyway in SSIS to wait for source DB connection to come back and start the extraction without failing the package? Because my source DB has 180 million data and I need to extract from there.

I am using SSIS 2008

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Why not have the restore job kick off this ssis package when it is done?

Comment: Try changing the isolation level of the package.   Maybe "Snapshot" would work.